# Rename Android Studio package error: Not a valid identifier name

Tags: android

Renaming from com.example.test to org.example.test: I have only found examples of changing the *example* part of this, but I need to change the *com* one.

I have tried Refactor then select Rename package, but I get the message *Not a valid identifier name* when I enter *org.example.test.*

Does anyone know the correct way?

Comment: Was there a specific reason as to why you didn't do it when creating the project?

Comment: There could be countless reasons - changing opinions as to what is best, changing or previously poorly communicated requirements, adopting code from a different source.  This is a very common and entirely legitimate need, so it's not particularly helpful to treat it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do the same a few months ago. As far as I know, Android Studio does not bound java packages with the app package. That said, you may have to change your app package (if that's what you want) and your java package.

**First, your Java package**

Select the **1. Project** tab in Android Studio. There's a Settings button. Click on it and check **Flatten Packages**.
Then, select the package you want to rename. Press `Shift + F6` to rename the whole package. If you have more than one package inside `com.example.test`, Android Studio will warn you "Multiple directories correspond to package..." and ask if you want to rename package or directory. Choose package and it will do its magic.

Unless you have something else other than `test` under `com.example`, you're good to go.

**Then, your Android app**

For this one, I don't know any shortcuts. But if it helps, the app package is mentioned in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` for your module.

Comment: Many thanks, sir, and I will give it a try. This is needed as the original was created ages ago as a test project before there was any intention of ever using _Google Play_.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution did not work for me. I had to do the following:

1. Create a new package with the desired name (eg. org.example.test)
2. Move the files from the old package to the new one [android studio correct the package name automatically]
3. In AndroidManifest.xml, change package="..." to the new one (eg. org.example.test) [maybe this step is not obligatory]
4. Compile. You will see errors like imports to the old package. Simply correct them one by one [I just found one error]

That's all. It run perfectly after that!